# Are hash sets worse in space complexity if there are a lot of inputs and removals?

Tags: hashset, space-complexity

Let’s say I have a hash set that I decide will only ever have 3 elements in it. But, I insert and remove, for example, N gibberish words at random while never having more than 3 elements in the set at a time.

Would the space complexity of this set still be o(1), or does the fact that I’m potentially inserting and then removing a million (or whatever) inputs mutate the hash set so that the size of the set is proportional to N in some way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will depend on the specific hash table implementation that you’re using, but a “good” implementation of a hash table should have no trouble doing this in O(1) space.

More specifically:

1. If you’re using a chained hash table, the table will typically only resize if the load factor (ratio of elements to table slots) exceeds some threshold. If the total number of elements is always at most three, then this condition will never trigger.
2. If you’re using a cuckoo hash table, as in case (1) the tables will only resize once the load factor is high, so with only three active elements the table should not resize once it’s big enough to hold three items while maintaining its load factor.
3. For a linear probing table or another open addressing table (quadratic probing, double hashing, etc.), deleted elements are marked with tombstones, which can cause the table to fill up with used slots after multiple elements are removed. However, a reasonable table implementation can easily address this by rebuilding the table at its current size once the number of tombstones is too large. As a result, the size should not depend on the total number of elements that have been inserted in the past.
4. For a Robin Hood hash table with backward shift deletion, tombstones aren’t needed, and the table size shouldn’t increase.

This doesn’t mean, however, that all implementations of hash tables would actually do this, though. Rather, it just means that no “standard” hash table would actually need to grow based on the number of elements that have ever been added rather than the max number of elements stored at any one point.

That being said, I do wonder if hashing is even the right idea here. If you know you’ll only be dealing with three items at a time and are concerned about performance, it might be faster to just make three variables holding your three items and then just check each one.

Comment: Thank you, this is a very clear answer. As for whether or not I should use a hash table/set, this was just a question that occurred to me with no real-life counterpart.

Answer (score 2):

The space-complexity of a hash table is O(N+H), where N is the (maximum) number of elements placed in the hash table and H is the hash table's original size (usually constant).

For example, if your hash function is `X % 51`, then there are 51 boxes to store your elements. This is O(1), a fixed size. In the event of a hash collision, you can use a linked list (or another hash function) to store multiple elements in a single box. This will increase the memory requirements proportional to the number of elements being stored in the hash table, making the size O(N).

If you keep inserting and removing elements in a manner such that there are never more than 3 elements (N=3) being stored in the hash table, the size of the hash table is O(1), since both the original size and maximum number of elements is a constant. Inserting and removing elements doesn't in any way change the hash function.

Comment: I just noticed that you asked about "hash set"s, not "hash table"s. My guess is that most hash sets are actually implemented as hash tables, with the special rule that in the event of a hash conflict, one instance of each element is stored.

Comment: This isn't really a special rule; a hashtable used as a dictionary also only allows one instance of each key.